# Encryption / decryption of binary data in the browser

Tags: javascript, browser, binary-data

I am working on a project that requires a client to de-crypt binary data received from the server. The scenario is that a server has binary data in a compressed and encrypted form. The browser needs to receive this data (files), decrypt and decompress them and then download them to a user-specified location on the local machine. I understand that their are several limitations of doing this in the browser -

1. Does Javascript have access to the local storage. Can I write/stream multiple files to a user-specified location on the hard drive? If so, what APIs to look for.
2. Can Javascript (or any other technology) be used in the browser to decrypt (AES-256) and decompress this data stream within the browser?

Can these issues be solved using the [FileAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) of HTML5?

**EDIT:**
Replaced SHA2 with AES. We are using SHA2 for integrity check, not for encryption.That was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't directly access the user's file system. Though, the [HTML5 file system API](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html5-filesystem/info) can be used to save data in a virtual, sandboxed filesystem.
2. CryptoJS has an [implementation](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#SHA-2) for SHA-2

To receive the data from the server, I suggest to use `XMLHttpRequest` with [`responseType = "arraybuffer"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-responsetype-attribute).

Comment: Regarding your updated question: CryptoJS also supports AES (AES-128, AES-192 and AES-256): http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a javascript cryptography library, here is one: http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Answer (score 0):

SHA-2 is not a means of encrypting or decrypting data, its a hash algorithm, it is used to determine if data has been tampered with.  Encryption algorithms are: DES, 3-DES, AES etc.

I suspect you need to generate a hash on the data you have and compare with the hash you have  received.

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo. I have updated the algorithm to AES.