# CSV file protected by password

Tags: node.js, typescript

Is it possible to create a csv file protected by password?

I can't find library. I tried with "security-json-to-csv" but it didn't work.

Comment: no but you can with zipjs

Comment: I don't want to use zip folder

Comment: A csv file is a text file. Text files don't internally have this capability. However, it's just a file. If you don't like the idea of zipping wth a password, there are plenty of other ways to encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV format does not have a way to "password-protect" it, but there are other ways to achieve this:

- Encrypt the file (maybe using [crypto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680431/how-can-i-encrypt-decrypt-arbitrary-binary-files-using-javascript-in-the-browser))
- ZIP it then password protect the zip.